# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory Eror

Tags: java, android

Hello Application Can I help getting this error too?

Whatever I did I couldn't fix this error.

```
Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process.
        This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
        For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
        Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
        Please read the following process output to find out more:
        -----------------------
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.CompositeStoppable.<clinit>(CompositeStoppable.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.tryClose(ClassLoaderUtils.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main(GradleDaemon.java:22)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

Comment: Can you add more information to the question? Currently, it seems like that the dependency for LoggerFactory isn't pulled in by the dependency management tool that you are using.

Comment: Frankly, I don't have much idea. I bought a mobile application from Codecanyon, I followed the steps, but I get this error.

Comment: I hope this helps - https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-fix-exception-in-thread-main.html